# Polymorphism example in Spring Boot. How to access methods of implementation class with the bean of the interface?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, polymorphism, autowired, spring-bean

**EDIT :** If i declare all the variables in my interface they should be public by default, which opposes encapsulation and i know that i can go with abstract class instead of interface. But, **in my question the main point is focused on Spring dependency injection**, how can i get an object of the implementation class to access its own methods, i have used `@Qualifier` but it doesn't seem to work.

I have an interface  with the name Account and its two implementation classes SavingsAccount and SalaryAccount. A customer class linking account details with customer with the help of an account object defined in customer class. Please go through the example for a better understanding.

My question is how to access the methods of SavingsAccount in Customer class with the spring bean of the SavingsAccount which is autowired.

If I hardcode something like `SavingsAccount sa = new Savingsccount();` in the customer class i can achieve accessing the methods of the SavingsAccount class. In spring i have to do that using `@Autowired`and `@Qualifier` annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("savingsAccount")
private Account account;
```

But i cannot access the methods of the savingsAccount with the spring bean  `account.getAccNum();`, like it is done with `sa.getAccNum;`

## **The complete example:**

```
public interface Account {
     public double showFunds();}
```

```
@Component
public class SalaryAccount implements Account {
    
     private long accNum;
     private double funds;
    // getter setter methods
    
    @Override
    public double showFunds() {
            return funds;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class SavingsAccount implements Account {
    
     private long accNum;
     private double funds;
    // getter setter methods
    
    @Override
    public double showFunds() {
            return funds;
    }
}
```

I have used autowired annotation along with qualifier, so that i get a spring bean of the implementation class specified in the @Qualifier

```
@Component
public class Customer {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private long mobile;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("savingsAccount")
    private Account account;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    public Customer(int id, String name, long mobile, Account account) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.account = account;
    }
    //getters and setters
    
    public void customerAccountProfile(){

       // here if i want to access members and variables of Savingsaccount with the bean account. How?

       account.getAccNum() ;// throws error

       account.showFunds();// works fine beacause it is defined in the interface Account

       System.out.println("do nothing");
       }
}
```

Comment: You can only access what is defined in the interface. If that isn't what you want then what is the purpose of the interface? Looking at the method you use this from, the `getAccNum` should simply be part of the `Account` interface.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah, i got your point, i could have used an abstract class instead of an interface to achieve my goal. But is there a way where i can get a spring bean of the implementation class to access its own methods. i thought `@Qualifier` will give me a bean of the implementation class specified with the @Qualifier annotation.

Comment: It still will be the class however it will only be accessible through the `Account` interface because that is the type you injected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all variables and methods in interface for access as below:

```
public interface Account {
 long accNum;
 double showFunds();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the accNum cannot be public, it has to be a a private variable. Please do read the question again, i have updated it again. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any proper answer yet, so I am posting this so it might help people in the future.

Solution: I think in the `@Component` on the `SavingsAccount` class, you can use the bean name. Like here, you can use `@Component("savingsAccount")`. And then pass it with the `@Qualifier` annotation in the `Customer` class.